# SQL Server backup using powershell in Task scheduler

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am using PowerShell to backup a SQL Server database and use Windows task scheduler to schedule the script

**Test**

1. Run the script manually, it works.
   Both SQL Server backup file (`test.bak`) and test file (`HelloWorld.txt`) were created.
2. Run via Windows task scheduler, only `HelloWorld.txt` was created, the SQL Server backup file was not created.

So at least;

1. The PowerShell script did run.
2. Credentials were ok for the manual run

**Problem**

Why is the SQL SErver backup file not created when run from Windows task scheduler?

Here is my `SQLbackup.ps1` file:

```
$credential = import-clixml -path c:\pp\test\sqlcred.xml
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance Server264\SUPPORT2K19 -Database PPTest -BackupAction Database -BackupFile "C:\PP\Test\Test.bak" -Credential $credential

Set-Content -Path "C:\PP\Test\HelloWorld.txt" -Value "Hello World"
```

Task scheduler settings are:

- User is SYSTEM,
- Select run whether user is logged on on or not
- Tick run with highest privilege

In action tab:

- Program: powershell
- Add arguments: `-executionpolicy bypass -file C:\PP\Test\sqlbackup.ps1`

Any suggestion why the SQL Server backup file was not created?

Comment: When you run it manually, are you running as system? System won’t be able to read credentials exported with a different user

Comment: good point ! when I test manually, I was using my username. not as system. I had to use system user for scheduled tasks to avoid username/password changes, and ensure the backup is always run.

Comment: @DougMaurer, I logged in as SYSTEM user, via psexec64 utility. re-generated the credential file. Issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

I think the cmdlet `Backup-SqlDatabase` produce an error, and you do not have a mechanism to capture that.

Try implementing `try/catch` to capture the error and then you can do what you want with that information, for example :

```
$credential = import-clixml -path c:\pp\test\sqlcred.xml
try {
    Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance Server264\SUPPORT2K19 -Database PPTest -BackupAction Database -BackupFile "C:\PP\Test\Test.bak" -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Set-Content -Path "C:\PP\Test\Error.txt" -Value "$_"
}
Set-Content -Path "C:\PP\Test\HelloWorld.txt" -Value "Hello World"
```

This would capture the potential `error` and write it in a `Error.txt` file, same way as the `HelloWorld.txt`.

Important part is that `Try/Catch` capture only terminating errors, so we add the `-ErrorAction Stop` at the end of the cmdlet to make any error terminating so we can execute the script in the `catch` script block.

You can read more about it in the Microsoft docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2

P.S. The documentation is for Powershell 7.2

Comment: great advice(+1). I have implemented your suggestion, and it returned following error in the error log: The system cannot find the path specified. On further investigation, I found the error was at "import-clixml -path c:\pp\test\sqlcred.xml".  Error message was misleading. it is permission issue rather than path not found.

Comment: I guess this answer "why backup file is not created". As for the error you described, it might be that the account used for the database not having sufficient access, you can look up this discussions - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/db-backup-error-cannot-find-the-path-specified